# How to login to salesforce from mavens mate?

Tags: mavensmate

I'm newbie with sublime text/mavens mate.  How can I do the equivalent of the eclipse option: "show in salesforce web" with windows version of mavens mate and sublime text?

Answer (score 2):

Press CTRL+SHIFT+P to get the command palette (COMMAND+SHIFT+P on Mac) and use the "MavensMate: Open in Web Browser" to do what you want. The command palette is great to search with in. I usually enter "mave" to get all the MavenMate commands - this particular case "mave web" would narrow down the number results to just a few number of items.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Now I get there are no valid files to open error.  I can see the changes to the apex class in salesforce.  When I highlight that class in sublime text, and enter the open in web browser, I get that error.

Comment: I ran into this issue as well. What I did was to close down project and reopening it using the "Project menu" instead of using the "Open Project" under the Mavens Mate menu - and it worked. After doing this once I could view the file independently of how I opened the project. Let me know if this help you so that I can report it as a bug to the MM project. Thanks!

Comment: I tried it: Project close, then Open using Project menu (when prompted, selected the project file in the project directory).  I get the same error.